# MediaPlayer convert from milliseconds to minutes and seconds

Tags: java, android

Class MediaPlayer have methods such as getCurrentPosition will return the value in milliseconds.

Heres the problem, when I get the value I use the class TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds and toMinutes, but I dont get the right values.

The values I is

xx:xzy and y is changing each seconds and when reaching 9 the z changes.

I need in xx:xx

Comment: `TimeUnit` is not for such purposes, use `DateUtils#formatElapsedTime` instead: `Formats an elapsed time in the form "MM:SS" or "H:MM:SS" for display on the call-in-progress screen`

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int yourms = 3636600;
    int split[] = splitTime(yourms);
    System.out.println(yourms + " ms = " + split[0] + " minutes and " + split[1] + " seconds.");
}

public static int[] splitTime(int ms) {
    int ss = ms / 1000;
    int mm = ss / 60;
    ss = ss - (mm * 60);

    return new int[]{mm, ss};
}
```

Example Output:

```
3636600 ms = 60 minutes and 36 seconds.
```